# Firebase doesn't send notification through HTTP POST

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've been trying to implement a push notification sending method through HTTP POST, using Firebase.

When sending my requests, Firebase responds with a 200 code, and returns the ID of the app, but the devices won't receive the notification.

However, if the notification is sent though the notification console on firebase.google.com, the notification will be received successfully.

Here is an example of my request :

```
to : https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/hikong-cbe53/messages:send

Content-Type: application/json
Authorization : Bearer ya29.c.Elpt.....2gRqTt5FCVmROVwZias
Host: fcm.googleapis.com
Content-Length: 171

{
  "message": {
    "topic": "gamestart",
    "notification": {
      "body": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
      "title": "FCM Message",

    }
  }
}
```

The response is

```
43
{
  "name": "projects/hikong-cbe53/messages/7496558274452412399"
}

0
```

Why would the response be successful but the notification not sent to devices ? Is there any way I can track the request to find where it was dropped ?

Comment: Try without the comma after  _"FCM Message"_

Comment: Thank you, but I found out what the problem was, I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you who may encounter the same problem, be very careful when you write the **topic name** if you send push notifications.

My topic name was `gameStart`.

The request were issued to a topic called `gamestart` which doesn't exist.

Strangely, Firebase didn't respond with 400, as the topic didn't exist, but with a 200. I don't know if that's an expected behavior, but that's something to be careful with.